# How can i fix these reloading issus from the apache module?

Tags: javascript, html, apache, xampp, livereload

I'm currently working on an `add-on` for the **ckeditor**.

And until, I recently needed to switch from working directly with the html-files `('file:///C:/Users/.../index.html')` to working with an local Apache Webserver `(localhost or 127.0.0.1/index.html)`, I set up with `XAMPP`, the Javascript-files
that are included in the html file won't load properly.

Now matter how often I try to reload the html-file in my browser, the changes i made in my `js.files`,
won't load until a minute after the changes have been made. // Quite exactly a minute

*Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?*
It's quite anyoning and impossible to get any work done at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most probably the caching of the files loaded from the Apache HTTP Server. You can either attach a GET parameter to the URL which changes for every request (e.g. a timestamp), or you can disable caching for the resources in question in Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html#cachedisable or https://superuser.com/questions/131121/config-xampp-never-to-cache-pages-from-localhost).

To disable caching for files from localhost, add this line to "httpd.conf":

```
CacheDisable /local_files
```

Or look for the caching module `mod_cache` and remove the loading directive by commenting it out:

```
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine for localhost. Not for 127.0.0.1, but that's something I can live with ;).

Answer (score 0):

go to folder "\xampp\htdocs" create a folder for example test
place there your index.html file and in url type "localhost/test"
may this will work properly

or you doing something wrong in javascript?